# Rest API post method callout in Salesforce

Tags: rest, salesforce

I am calling rest. Get method running properly but when i am running post method it shows following error,

02:08:09.159 (1159191000)|USER_DEBUG|[139]|DEBUG|Message Body:[{"message":"Content-Type header specified in HTTP request is not supported: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","errorCode":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"}]

Answer (score 1):

Set the content type as `application/json`

Comment: thanks..i wrote application/json then how to pass paramter to post method.